# Как настроить WebSocket на ISP Manager на VDS?

Tags: php, javascript, websocket, ispmanager

Приветствую.

Пытаюсь сделать websocket на сайте, установил Ratchet настроил скрипт сервера чата для теста, как указано на сайте socketo.me

Сервер VDS установлена панель ISP Manager.

Через консоль запускается скрипт как показано в некоторых видео.

Пробую подключиться через сайт выдает ошибку

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://test.ru:4444/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Добавил в ISPmanager настройки Брандмауэр открыть порт 4444 с приемом от всех. Попробовал запустить websocket сервер - запустился, после пробую через консоль виндовса открыть telnet site.ru 4444 подключается к порту! Отлично...

Но через сайт не получается почему-то...

**проблема была в https**, попробовал на другом сайте где нет https получилось, данные приходят без проблем.

Вопрос: Как теперь через wss сделать? поставил wss но подключения не происходит, не подключается...

Comment: А файрволл не блочит это дело ? telnet открывает порт ?

Comment: попробовал через консоль винды порт не открывает. Наверное файрвол его не пускает

Comment: С этого и стоит начать

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov короче, добавил я в настройки Брандмауэр открыть порт 4444 с приемом от всех. Попробовал запустить websocket серврер - запустился, через консоль виндовса пробую открыть telnet site.ru 4444 подключается к порту! Через скрипт на сайте не получается пока-что...

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov проблема была в https, попробовал на другом сайте где нет https получилось, данные приходят без проблем.

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov беда теперь с wss не работает через него почему-то =/

Comment: Я к сожалению с ним ни разу не работал

Comment: Ставьте nginx и в нём настраивайте https

Comment: @andreymal на другом сайте уже стоит https просто не понятно почему не работает wss

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev wss — это ws через https, а у вас на порту 4444 никакого https видимо нет. Ставьте nginx и в нём настраивайте https

Comment: @andreymal наверное... честно первый раз с этим сталкиваюсь

Comment: @andreymal а что мне надо сделать nginx какие настройки?

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev настроить его так, чтобы он проксировал вебсокет-запросы на этот ваш порт 4444, а браузер потом должен будет подключаться не к порту 4444, а к nginx (мне расписывать это сейчас лень, но инфа в интернете есть)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем кто пытался помочь, тем кто посылал конфиги почитать вам "спасибо", ответа так и не получил в итоге решил сам, вот [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/757351/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8-nginx-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-websocket/757402#757402)