# Помогите с прокси Nginx для WebSocket

Tags: php, nginx, proxy, ispmanager

Нужна помощь с настройкой конфигураций.

Панель сервера ISP manager установлен Nginx на сайтах стоит SSL сертификаты.

Использую библиотеку Ratchet для работы с WebSocket она не поддерживает работу с SSL. Получается нужно сделать прокси...

Открыл порт 4444 (проверял telnet-ом работает), запустил сервер WebSocket и он работает, если обращаться напрямую.

Конфигурации основного файла Nginx `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user  apache;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  30;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts/*/*.conf;

    server {
        server_name localhost;
        disable_symlinks if_not_owner;
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
        location @fallback {
            error_log /dev/null crit;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            access_log off ;
        }


    }
    client_max_body_size 10m;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
}
```

Конфигурация файла Nginx для сайта:

```
erver {
    server_name site.ru *.site.ru www.site.ru;
    charset off;
    index index.html index.php;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/site.ru/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.ru.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.ru.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    return 301 https://$host:443$request_uri;
    set $root_path /var/www/site/data/www/site.ru;
    root $root_path;
    listen 91.215.129.119:80;
    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        }
        location / {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
    }
    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        access_log off;
    }
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
}
server {
    server_name site.ru *.site.ru www.site.ru;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/site/site_le1.crtca";
    ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/site/site_le1.key";
    ssl_ciphers EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:!NULL:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam4096.pem;
    charset off;
    index index.html index.php;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/site.ru/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.ru.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.ru.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    set $root_path /var/www/site/data/www/site.ru;
    root $root_path;
    listen 91.215.129.119:443;
    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        }
        location / {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
    }
    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        access_log off;
    }
    location /websocket/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4444;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:4444 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        access_log off;
    }
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
}
```

Я честно скажу уже измучался, объяснения нормального и понятного не нашел в работе прокси и настройки.

Единственное, обнаружил, при текущих настройках по адресу https://site.ru/websocket/ открывает 502 ошибку (пишет об этом на странице), но когда когда запускаешь websocket сервер, то на странице ничего уже не показывает, а в консоле показывает GET https://site.ru/websocket/ 505 (HTTP Version not supported)...

Как настроить не могу понять... помогите...

Comment: где нужные заголовки? http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/websocket.html

Comment: какие нужные заголовки, вы можете не посылать в то-что я уже 10 раз прочел! Покажите что я сделал неправильно и поясните нормальным человеческим языком, а не посылайте куда-то перечитать

Comment: Во-вторых, я написал что есть конфиг ОСНОВНОЙ и у отдельного КОНКРЕТНОГО сайта, куда вписывать? В мануале не могу найти слова об этом...

Comment: @norbornen решил сам, оказывается нужно  было сделать так, кое-что вписать в основной конфиг в блок http{}, и location /websocket {...} указать в конфиге сайта, сразу все заработало!

Comment: `какие нужные заголовки, вы можете не посылать в то-что я уже 10 раз прочел` на странице документации речь идёт только про заголовки выставляемые с помощью директивы proxy_set_header, в примерах эта директива устанавливается только в контексте location-а. то есть совсем небольшим мозговым усилием вы могли догадаться, что речь про `proxy_set_header Upgrade` и `proxy_set_header Connection` в вашем `location /websocket/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решил проблему сам (месяц почти мучался)

Вот настройка подключения WebSocket через SSL используя библиотеку Ratchet,  сервер с панелью ISP Manager через Nginx+PHP:

Первым делом открываем порт в Брандмауре, я открыл 4444 порт.

В главный конфиг Nginx `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` вписать:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }
    upstream websocket {
      server IP_вашего_сервера:4444;
    }
```

и еще чтобы пользователя не отключало быстро

```
keepalive_timeout 86400;
proxy_connect_timeout 86400;
proxy_send_timeout 86400;
proxy_read_timeout 86400;
```

В конфиге Nginx сайта /etc/nginx/vhosts/site.ru/site.ru.conf в блок server дописать:

```
location /websocket {
            proxy_pass http://websocket;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
```

Поясню `upstream websocket {...}`, где **websoсket** может быть любым названием, как вам угодно, только обязательно в конфигурации для сайта используйте в `location /websocket {proxy_pass http://websocket; ...}` такое же название иначе работать не будет!

В подключении к WebSocket через JS используем такую конструкцию ссылки:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('wss://site.ru/websocket');
```

Надеюсь понятно объяснил!